# IndexOf with custom Lists (Flutter - Dart)

Tags: list, flutter, dart, indexof

I want to get the Index of the ***ListA with the name test*** in this list

**First class**

```
class ListA {
  String name;

  ListA({this.name});
}
```

**Second class**

```
List<ListA> abc = [

  ListA(name: 'test'),

];
```

*after that, i got a statless Wiget with a button,
that is the onPressed-method*

```
onPressed: () {
            i = abc.indexOf(ListA(name: 'test'));
            print(i);
          },
```

*I couldn´t find any misstakes, but unfortunately it´s always returning -1, what means it couldn´t find it*

**What am i doing wrong ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you're creating a new `ListA` when calling `indexOf`, and that means you have two different `ListA`s. This is similar to doing:

```
print(ListA(name: 'test') == ListA(name: 'test'));
```

This will print `false` because they're not the same object.

You could try one of the following:

1. Keep a reference to the first `ListA` you use, and call `indexOf` passing the same reference in
2. Use `const` instances of `ListA` (mark the `name` field as `final`, add `const` to the constructor definition and the calls to it)
3. Override the [`==` operator](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) and [`hashCode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html) on your `ListA` class, so that the two different instances of `ListA` are considered the same if their fields/items are the same
4. Instead of `indexOf`, use `indexWhere` and check the name (`indexWhere((l) => l.name == 'test')`)